# Template for Views PDF

Tags: files

I want to build a PDF with fields of a node. I installed [Views PDF](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_pdf). Now I try to create a node tpl file. But [Views PDF](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_pdf) doesn't use my template.

How can I create a template, that is used by [Views PDF](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_pdf)?

thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any template files. All you need to do is to create a pdf document with d design u want, then include it in the template section in your views setup

Comment: Could you elaborate on this? Some screenshots of prepared pdf, configuration and actual result would help. I can't recall seeing anything like this, and your answer didn't help me to find it.